# Changing Chapter Title in scrrprt-class

Tags: formatting, chapters, scrreprt

I am using the scrrprt-class and would like my chapter titles to have the following layout:

[image: Desired layout]

How can I achieve this?

Note that the chapter shall appear in the pdfbookmarks as "1 Introduction".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `chapterprefix` document class option to get the 'Chapter xx' titles.
For the numbered bookmarks, you can load the `bookmark` package with the `numbered` option, like so:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The below code contains two further adjustments, one for changing vertical distance between the "Chapter xx" and the chapter title, and another for changing the font size of the "Chapter xx".

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=0pt]{chapter} % <--- Vary distance here (Thanks @esdd!)


\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\large} % Default is \LARGE

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Now: How can I reduce the vertical spacing between the two lines? And how can I make the prefix smaller in size compared to the actual chapter title?

Comment: @Daniel See update. In the future, please do provide a minimal, compilable code (what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) like what I have shown above when asking questions on this site.

Comment: To change the vertical distance between the two lines use `\RedeclareSectionCommand[innerskip=0pt]{chapter}`